# Python telebot. How send messages if user don't do anything?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telegram-api

I'm new in telegram bot building, the problem is, how is possible to send a message to the user if he does nothing for 12 hours, then send another one if he continues to do nothing? But if he clicks on the button in the message 4 for example, it skips message 5.

```
if call.data == 'GetLesson1':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, mg.third_message, reply_markup=kb.check_exercise())
        push_data.append(call.data)
if call.data == 'Exercise':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, mg.sixth_message, reply_markup=kb.check_exercise())

time.sleep(54000)

if call.data is None:
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, mg.fourth_message, reply_markup=kb.check_exercise())

time.sleep(54000)

if call.data is None:
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, mg.fives_message, reply_markup=kb.check_exercise())
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to read about [`JobQueue`](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-JobQueue) that is available in [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-JobQueue).

Here is an example, how to send message in a minute:

```py
def callback_minute(context: telegram.ext.CallbackContext):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id='@examplechannel', 
                             text='One message every minute')

job_minute = j.run_repeating(callback_minute, interval=60, first=0)
```

Inside that callback you can have some check if user send anything from that time, or even remove this job completely when you get new message (so no checks needed).

```py
job_minute.schedule_removal()
```

See [more examples](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-JobQueue) in documentation.